# Make onetime page Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am making an application in VS2012 for Windows Phone 8, C#/XAML.
Now, I want to make a page that will run only when the app is installed and user opens the app for first time.
Not anytime after that.

Kindly Help,
Thanking You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an XML file to write a value that says whether or not the page has already been displayed. So in this page's constructor (or more appropriately in it's OnLoad event) you can write the value to the XML file and say it's already been displayed. Then in your startup logic you can read this file and if that value has already been set, you can skip to a different page.

Xml File

```
<StartupValues>
    <HasFirstTimePageDisplayed>True</HasFirstTimePageDisplayed>
</StartupValues>
```

Page-You-Want-To-Show-Once

Xaml

```
<Page Loaded="OnLoaded" ... />
```

Xaml.Cs

```
public void OnLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
    var xml = new XmlSerializer( typeof( StartupValues ) );
    using( var writer = new StreamWriter( "config_file_path_here.xml" ) )
    {
        xml.Serialize( new StartupValues
            {
                HasFirstTimePageDisplayed = true
            }, writer.BaseStream );            
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public void OnStartup( ... ) // I forget what the method signature for this is
{
    bool displayFirstPage = true;

    var xml = new XmlSerializer( typeof( StartupValues ) );
    using( var reader= new StreamReader( "config_file_path_here.xml" ) )
    {
        StartupValues values = xml.Deserialize( reader.BaseStream ) as StartupValues;
        displayFirstPage = values.HasFirstTimePageDisplayed;
    }

    if( displayFirstPage )
    {
        // display the page
    }
    else
    {
        // display a different page
    }
}
```

StartupObject.cs

```
public class StartupValues
{
    public bool HasFirstTimePageDisplayed { get; set; }
}
```

Some reading material relating to your problem:

[XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) Class

[StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) Class

[Page Navigation in WP8 Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[WP8 Dev Center](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) (A great place for resources)

Comment: sorry but can you show me some reference code or blog or something

Comment: The type or namespace name 'StartupValues' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That's an object you have to make. It needs to have properties that represent the values you want to read/write from the Xml file.

Comment: I am a beginner and a noob in this...please help me

Comment: I did, and it's okay to be a noob. I added the class to my answer. If there's anything else you're unsure of relating to my answer, you can ask and also google. I'll add some links to it so you have some reading material. But I can't really explain it more thoroughly than that. Also, remember to mark as answer!

Comment: am facing few errors. It would be great if you help me resolving it

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(System.IO.Stream, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SampleApp1.StartupValues' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Error 3 The name 'writer' does not exist in the current context           App.xaml.cs

Error 4 'object' does not contain a definition for 'HasFirstTimePageDisplayed' and no extension method 'HasFirstTimePageDisplayed' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)      App.xaml.cs

Comment: Just added some edits. Check them out.

Comment: thank you but still 1st error is there